# I am unable to reach my site if I omit the url scheme (https)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-acm

I have an IIS server and I have deployed a couple of websites on it each using their separate bindings. The sites are deployed on a single EC2 instance behind an application load-balancer (using an autoscaling group)

site bindings:

```
login.aws.mysite.com
api.aws.mysite.com
```

I am using Route 53 for my DNS service and I have created a public hosted zone for my site `mysite.com` there and 2 records both pointing to the load-balancer.

An issue that I have discovered when accessing the site is that when I omit the URL scheme of the URL such as `login.aws.mysite.com` I am unable to reach my website, my request just times out. However, if I add the URL scheme (I use SSL) like so `https://login.aws.mysite.com` it works fine.

These are the listeners I have configured for my load-balancer:
[image]
The port `80` listener is set up to redirect to the secure port `443`.

`curl -v http://login.aws.mysite.com` output:

```
PS C:\Users\georgi.koemdzhiev> curl -v http://login.aws.mysite.com

* Connected to login.aws.mysite.com (10.201.202.111) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: login.aws.mysite.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection was reset
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset
```

Is there a way I can omit the URL schema and still reach `https://login.aws.mysite.com`? I am not sure if this is an issue with my load-balancer or Route 53.

**Notes**:

1. I have created a single SSL certificate using AWS ACM that I am using on the website using this domain - `*.aws.mysite.com`
2. I have setup a HTTPS redirection on my load-balander

Comment: If **https** works but **http** does not, then you either do not have a listener for port 80 configured correctly or your redirect logic is broken. Edit your question with details.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @JohnHanley, I have added my load-balancer listener configuration in my answer.

Comment: Neither of my suggestions is the cause. Use the CLI command **curl** and post the command and output in your question: `curl -v http://login.aws.mysite.com`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, John. I have updated my question with the curl command output

Comment: The error indicates that the listener is not configured correctly. I do not see a problem with the listener, so I do not know. Connection reset means the other side does not like your connection.

Comment: That's interesting, thank you for your input, Jhon. That narrows the places where I should be looking. Appreciate your time.